# Specify spatial resolution using Rasterio rasterize

Tags: python, gdal, rasterio, resolution

I am converting vector features to raster using Rasterio [`rasterize`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.features.html?highlight=rasterize#rasterio.features.rasterize)(). I am trying to find a way to specify the output spatial resolution. The current approach specifies the number of pixels (`shape = 100, 100`) in the XY dimensions.

```
import geopandas as gpd
from rasterio.features import rasterize

gdf = gpd.read_file('/path/to/polylines.shp')

shape = 100, 100
transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(*gdf['geometry'].total_bounds, *shape)


raster = rasterize(
    [(shape, 1) for shape in gdf['geometry']],
    out_shape=shape,
    transform=transform,
    fill=0,
    all_touched=True,
    dtype=rasterio.uint8)
```

The following GDAL approach does what I am after, although I need to stay within the Rasterio package:

```
import gdal
import ogr

# https://stackoverflow.com/a/59892342

lines = '/path/to/poly_lines.shp'
input_shp = ogr.Open(lines)
output_raster = '/path/to/out_raster.tif'
shp_layer = input_shp.GetLayer()

pixel_size = 30
xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax = shp_layer.GetExtent()

ds = gdal.Rasterize(output_raster, 
                    lines, 
                    xRes=pixel_size, 
                    yRes=pixel_size, 
                    burnValues=1, 
                    outputBounds=[xmin, ymin, xmax, ymax], 
                    allTouched=True,
                    outputType=gdal.GDT_Byte)
ds = None
```

How can I specify the spatial resolution when using Rasterio `rasterize()`?

Answer (score 3):

I believe it's implied by the transform, so just calculate the width and height you need when initializing that to meet your target pixel size.  Something like this (untested):

```
import math

pixel_size = 30.0

min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = bounds = gdf['geometry'].total_bounds
w_px = math.ceil((max_x - min_x) / pixel_size)
h_px = math.ceil((max_y - min_y) / pixel_size)

transform = rasterio.transform.from_bounds(*bounds, w_px, h_px)
```

You might also be able to use [`transform.from_origin`](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.transform.html#rasterio.transform.from_origin):

```
min_x, min_y, max_x, max_y = gdf['geometry'].total_bounds
transform = rasterio.transform.from_origin(west=min_x, north=max_y, xsize=pixel_size, y_size=pixel_size)
```